# assistance require resolving jslint errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, jshint

I am currently running JSLint against the javascript in my web application and getting some errors that I require assistance with resolving.

a. First error I am getting is: JS Lint: Unused Variable 'n'.

```
 $.each(collection, function (n, item) {
                var temp = item.Id;
        // do further processing
    });
```

b. I have all my javascript declared in a self executing function like such:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
// further javascript code
}
(jQuery));
```

The above pattern can protect the $ from conflicting with other JavaScript libraries and also protect undefined from being redefined. However I get these errors from it:

JS Lint: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'undefined' (a reserved word). 
JS Lint: Unused Variable 'undefined'.

c. JS Lint: Unescaped '-'.

```
 if (value.match(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)) {
    return true;
 }
```

d. JS Lint: Type confusion: 'printer-': string and '(': number.

```
  var frameName = "printer-" + new Date().getTime();
```

I get numerous errors of Type confusion, sometimes with numbers, integers and other data types. Any idea as to how I can prevent getting these?

e. JS Lint: Insecure '^'.

```
var value = value.replace(/[^\d\.,\-]/gi, '');
```

f. JS Lint: Don't make functions within a loop.

```
for (i = 0, l = txts.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(txts[i].getAttribute("maxlength"))) {
            var func = function () {
                //do some processing
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and then we can run it against JS Lint and see, and resolve, the relevant errors.

Comment: You cannot resolve all "errors". Some are unavoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A.) See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

you can use:

```
$.each(collection, function() {
    doSomething(this); // this refers to the current iteration
});
```

B.) If you aren't actually using "undefined" you aren't protecting it from anything

C.) I'm not going to bother with regex lol EDIT: Perhaps it wants `[A-Z0-9\-]`

D.) You are concatenating string with number.  Try `'string' + Date.getTime().toString()` instead

See also [JSLint Type Confusion: function and object with jQuery .css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454446/jslint-type-confusion-function-and-object-with-jquery-css) for type confusion stuff, there are some oddities that I don't agree with

E.) Again I'm not going to try for the regex EDIT: Here's an identical question though: [JSLint "insecure ^" in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109214/jslint-insecure-in-regular-expression)

F.) If you can create your function once outside of the loop and then use it inside the loop (as long as you do it well) it is a significant performance increase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer on this. Re B., yes I am using undefined in my javascript functions within this self executing function and this error still occurs, any idea why?

Comment: @amateur JSLint is pretty good for getting close to correct but is not exactly correct. "undefined", though it claims is a reserved word, is not yet a reserved word.  Your use is correct, so it is valid to ignore those errors.  When "undefined" does truly get specced as a reserved word then it will not be fine to ignore it.

Comment: @amateur I've updated my answer and pointed at another similar question for E

Comment: thanks go the update. Can I turn off the rule for this or at least update it's treatment of 'undefined'? I can ignore it but I aiming for no errors ;-)

Comment: @amateur  I couldn't find a way to turn it off but you could use the community driven http://jshint.com/ which seems to be a little more "real-world" than jsLint  I ran some test code similar to yours (using undefined) and it passes without errors.  Jshint is based on jslint so it should still be a good sanity check.

Comment: lovely, going to try jshint - interested to which I should use long term in my applications but will open another question on that!

Answer (score 1):

I see others have answered, so I'll at least put an attempt in for c)

> c. JS Lint: Unescaped '-'.
>
> ```
> if (value.match(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)) {
>    return true;
> }
> ```

C. Add a backslash before the - in `9-` and `+-`

Sorry, can't help you with E), that regex looks ok to me.